# Что почитать про план запроса?

Tags: sql-server

Посоветуйте, что почитать, чтобы обрести понимание работы с планами запросов MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SQL Server Execution Plans" (Second Edition) By Grant Fritchey - все очень подробно расписано.